# How to debug tactic failure in a match goal branch?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Let's say I have some complex tactics in the body of a `match goal` branch that can easily go wrong in a way I might need to debug. Is there a way to get the "real" error message from the branch if some tactic fails, rather than simply getting "Error: No matching clauses for match goal"?

Take as an example this fake tactic where `apply A, B, C` has several chances for something to go wrong. I've been fighting with a real tactic somewhat similar to this today.

```
Ltac three_applications :=
    match goal with
        | [
            A : (* something reasonable *),
            B : (* something reasonable *),
            C : (* something reasonable *)
        |- _ ]  =>
            idtac A B C;
            assert (F: (* something reasonable *))
                by apply A, B, C;
            solve [discriminate F]
    end.
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to use `lazymatch goal` instead but it has different semantics, but as I see you match only on one shape, it might be ok for you.

The idea is that `match goal` might backtrack: if you have

```
match goal with
| n : nat |- _ => destruct n ; reflexivity
| |- nat => exact 0
end.
```

it will first try to find some `n : nat` in your hypotheses, starting from the most recent, and then try the tactic `destruct n ; reflexivity`. If it fails, it will try to find another natural number. If all of them fail, then it will look if the goal matches the second clause instead, and if so execute `exact 0`.
If that fails again, it will backtrack once again and conclude that `No matching clauses for match goal`.

On the other hand,

```
lazymatch goal with
| n : nat |- _ => destruct n ; reflexivity
| |- nat => exact 0
end.
```

will find the first branch that matches, and then apply the tactic, if it fails, no backtracking in the `lazymatch`, and it will give you the error of the tactic in the corresponding branch.

Note that I would always use `lazymatch`, not just for debugging purposes, when I don't find a use case for backtracking.

---

In case, `lazymatch` is not semantically equivalent to your `match` and backtracking needs to be involved then it will be harder, but indeed, using `idtac A B C` can help you see which branch it selected before launching the error.
Sometimes, writing

```
Fail three_applications.
```

instead of just

```
three_applications.
```

will help because `Fail` will usually keep the printing that you made in the command, even if it failed in the end.

Once you know the branch, just apply your tactic manually.